# run a query using EXECUTE BLOCK to prepair a column for an unique-Index

Tags: php, sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have a column in a table that I want to use for an unique-index.

My script should make the data unique by concat the id of a record,
if the data of current record is duplicate.

I've learned that I need to put this inside a EXECUTE BLOCK.

```
EXECUTE BLOCK 
AS 
    DECLARE VARIABLE ID BI;
    DECLARE VARIABLE REASON XTXT;
    DECLARE VARIABLE LAST_REASON XTXT = '';

BEGIN
FOR SELECT 
            ID_STATEMENT, 
            REASON 
    FROM 
            STATEMENT
    WHERE
            ID_STATEMENT > 0
    ORDER BY
            REASON ASC
    INTO    :ID, 
            :REASON
DO BEGIN
IF ( REASON = LAST_REASON ) THEN
    UPDATE
          STATEMENT
    SET 
          REASON = :REASON || ' X' || :ID
    WHERE
          ID_STATEMENT = :ID;
END
LAST_REASON = REASON;
END
```

But I am getting an error-message:

> -104 Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 18, column 13

In line 18 starts the into-part, column 13 is the ':' in front of :ID,

I try this under PHP, driver is PDO.

Comment: The error in your question misses the actual unknown token (which the full error does report), which is `;`, and that is because there should not be a `;` after `INTO :ID, :REASON`. The `FOR SELECT ... INTO ... DO ...` should be considered a single statement.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the `INTO` clause in the edited version, the only problem left is the the comparison operator, it should be `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: @Bastian, what is your PHP version?

Comment: @BrakNicku: in the IF-Statement I changed it to = instead of ==. 
This does not help. I get the same error-message, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten a little further now.

The syntax problem with the colon has been resolved.

The reason I keep getting an error message is because of the colon
in the INTO line is a bug in the PDO-driver I use
under PHP.

Purely by coincidence, while researching another topic, I have
learn that this bug has existed since PHP version 5.6 and at least
not yet been eliminated by version 7.3.

This "EXECUTE BLOCK" is running very well:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK 
AS 
    DECLARE VARIABLE ID BI;
    DECLARE VARIABLE REASON XTXT;
    DECLARE VARIABLE LAST_REASON XTXT = '';
BEGIN
      FOR SELECT 
                  ID_STATEMENT, 
                  REASON 
          FROM 
                  STATEMENT
          WHERE
                  ID_STATEMENT > 0
          ORDER BY
                  REASON ASC
          INTO    :ID, 
                  :REASON
      DO 
        BEGIN
              IF (REASON = LAST_REASON) THEN BEGIN
                  UPDATE
                        STATEMENT
                  SET 
                        REASON = :REASON || ' X' || :ID
                  WHERE
                        ID_STATEMENT = :ID;
              END
              LAST_REASON = REASON;
        END
END
```

Driver: PHP Interbase- / Firebird-Driver

Important is the "BEGIN" after the "THEN" in the IF-Statement !!!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want to make field REASON unique. In this case it is simple:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK 
AS 
    DECLARE VARIABLE ID BLOB;
    DECLARE VARIABLE REASON XTXT;

BEGIN
FOR SELECT 
            REASON || LIST(ID_STATEMENT, 'X'),
            REASON 
    FROM 
            STATEMENT
    WHERE
            ID_STATEMENT > 0
    GROUP BY
            REASON
    HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    INTO    :ID, 
            :REASON
DO BEGIN
    DELETE FROM
          STATEMENT
    WHERE
          REASON = :REASON;
    INSERT INTO
          STATEMENT
    VALUES
          (:ID, :REASON);
END
END
```

After that in the table you'll have records with unique REASONs and concatenated IDs.

Comment: The table "STATEMENT" has 76 columns and I try one of them, the column "REASON",  to make unique.

The data of the other 75 colums by each record should not be touched.

Will your sql-statement do that ?

Comment: @BastianBlanc If you add them to the query - yes. But it is up to you what to do if values in these fields are different from record to record.